# Proving $f(z)=\int_{0}^1\sin(zt)/t\;dt$ is an entire function with Morera's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

This is from Bak and Newman exercise 7.11. Let 
$$f(z)=\int_{0}^1\frac{\sin zt}{t}dt.$$
Prove that $f(z)$ is entire from Morera's theorem.

This question will need to employ LDCT, Fubini's theorem. I will be delighted if someone can guide me step by step.

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: For any point $z_0$, consider the curve $\gamma(t) = z_0 + e^{i\theta}$. As for the rest - YOU should be figuring that out!

Comment: The problem is not that simple, I suppose. You will first need to argue continuity with LDCT and thete will be some conditions to check in order to apply Fubini's theorem. That's where my concerns come from.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_R$ define the open disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin on the complex plane.

> **Claim** $$\left|\frac{\sin w}{w}\right|\le\frac{\sinh(R)}{R}$$ for $w\in B_R$.

**Proof**

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\sin w}{w}\right|&=\left|\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}w^{2n}\right| \\
&\le \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{|w|^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \\
&\le \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{R^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \\
&=\frac{\sinh R}{R}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, let $\gamma$ be a rectifiable closed curve in $B_R$, then
$$\oint_\gamma\int^1_0 |z|\left|\frac{\sin zt}{zt}\right| dt |dz|\le R\cdot\frac{\sinh R}{R}\oint_{\gamma}|dz|<+\infty$$

Hence, by Fubini’s theorem,
$$\oint_\gamma\int^1_0 \frac{\sin zt}{t} dt dz
=\int^1_0\frac 1t\left(\oint_\gamma\sin zt\, dz\right)dt=0$$

By Monera’s theorem, $\displaystyle\int^1_0\frac{\sin zt}{t}dt$ is holomorphic on $B_R$. Since the choice of $R$ is arbitrary, it immediately follows that such function is entire.